# java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class org.apache.tomcat.websocket.pojo.PojoEndpointBase cannot access a member of class with modifiers "public"

Tags: java, tomcat8, tomcat9, java-websocket

We have our application running on tomcat 8.0.38. But we are migrating it to tomcat 9.0.78. We are using Java Websocket API for messages. After deploying the war on tomcat 9.0.78 we are getting the following error in catalina.out.

```
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.pojo.PojoEndpointBase.doOnOpen Failed to call onOpen method of POJO end point for POJO of type [com.sample.main.DemoService]
        java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class org.apache.tomcat.websocket.pojo.PojoEndpointBase cannot access a member of class com.sample.main.WebSocketService with modifiers "public"
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Reflection.java:361)
                at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:591)
                at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:558)
                at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.pojo.PojoEndpointBase.doOnOpen(PojoEndpointBase.java:67)
                at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.pojo.PojoEndpointServer.onOpen(PojoEndpointServer.java:46)
                at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsHttpUpgradeHandler.init(WsHttpUpgradeHandler.java:131)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:968)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1791)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
                at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

pseudo Code

```
package com.sample.main;

class WebSocketService {

private Set<Session> sessionSet;

  public Set<Session> getSessionSet() {
    return sessionSet;
  }

  public void setSessionSet(final Set<Session> sessionSet) {
    this.sessionSet = sessionSet;
  }

void initialize() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
  }

@OnOpen
  public void open(final Session session, final EndpointConfig config) {
    initialize();
    try {
      sessionSet.add(session);
      final HandshakeRequest httpReq =
          (HandshakeRequest) config.getUserProperties().get(HandshakeRequest.class.getName());
      final Object headers = httpReq == null ? null : httpReq.getHeaders();
      log.info("Websocket got connected with the session: " + session.getId() + " headers " + headers);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error("Error occured in opening session", e);
    }
  }

  @OnClose
  public void close(final Session session) {
    sessionSet.remove(session);
    log.info("Websocket got closed with the session: " + session.getId());
  }

  @OnError
  public void onError(final Session session, final Throwable error) {
    log.error("Error happened in websocket due to " + error.getMessage() + " for session "
        + session.getId());
    close(session);
  }

}
```

```
package com.sample.main;

public class DemoService extends WebSocketService {

private static final Set<Session> SESSION_SET = new CopyOnWriteArraySet<>();

@Override
  public void initialize() {
setSessionSet(SESSION_SET);
}

}
```

can someone please help what needs to be done. As the same code is working fine in tomcat 8 but not in tomcat 9.